# I need Flash Player 11.3.0 or higher

Tags: flash, chromium

I need to take some online tests for school.
This website tells me I need Flash Player 11.3.0 or higher. As far as I can see that is not yet avaible for Linux.
I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Chromium. Is there a way I can work around it?

Greetz. Rob.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get Flash Player 11.2+ is to use Google Chrome in Ubuntu. There is no other way to get it, because a higher version has not been released for Ubuntu.

[Download Google Chrome From Here](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/)

Select your OS version x86 or x64 and download it to any path.

Then you can open it with the Ubuntu Software Center to install.

You can also install by executing command:

```
sudo dpkg -i <googlechromefile.deb>
```

Hope it helps you somewhat!!

Comment: I don't know why did I get a thumb down. If someone really knows how to install `Flash Player 11.2+` in Ubuntu then post it here.. I am so eager to know!! I always want to stick with `Firefox` but because of Flash it doesn't allow me to access some sites!! If someone gives a thumb down! I just want to know why, so that I could know my mistake!!!

Comment: For information, there is now Pipelight (plugin based on Wine) http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/pipelight-020-released-with-multi.html or Pepper flash (used by Chrome) http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/install-pepper-flash-player-for.html

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install wine

Download Firefox for Windows

Visit Youtube and install the addon that pops up. You now have the latest version of Flash!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I didn't thought latest Flash player 11.9 works through Wine with Firefox! I had to install Flash Player with offline installer http://www.itechtics.com/flash-player-11-9-full-download/. I don't understand why you got downvoted. I tried the Pepper-based Flash Player on Chromium http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-pepper-flash-for-chromium-web-browser-on-ubuntu-gnulinux.html and got Flash 11.9 installed but some web apps like http://www.6play.fr/ didn't work correctly. Otherwise I would have suggested a Windows VM with Virtualbox.